# If Permission Denied open a new activity android

Tags: android

I am requesting user to Access or deny gps permission if user clicks Access permission then my code is working but when the user clicks on Deny permission i am not able to open another activity

here is my code:

```
 txtLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);

        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        boolean network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        Location location;

        if (network_enabled) {

            boolean permissionGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED;
            Log.d("permission", "onCreate: "+permissionGranted);
            if(permissionGranted) {
                // {Some Code}


            } else {

//               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 200);
         }


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    200);

        }


            location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if(location!=null){
                lat = location.getLongitude();
                lon = location.getLatitude();

                Log.d("lat", "onCreate: "+lat+","+lon);
                txtLocation.setText(+lat+","+lon);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Latitude:"+lat+"\n"+"Longitude:"+lon);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();


            }
        }




    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

        Log.d("", "onRequestPermissionsResult: "+requestCode);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 200: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Homepage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);



                }
            }

            default:{

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by not able to open? Does it crash?

Comment: @KamranAhmed no it doesnt crash but my code doesn't get called if Access is denied , i am not able to access the denied part in my code

Comment: you can use debug to see what is wrong.

Comment: @VladMatvienko i did but i am not getting it

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko how can i know if user denied permission ? thats my question

Comment: ok, does it enter the `onRequestPermissionsResult`?

Comment: @VladMatvienko yup it does

Comment: but i get code 200 everytime even if the access is denied

Comment: that's ok. It is a request code. It is like a name of the request. So you can determine, which response you've got. What does it return in `grantResults[0]`

Comment: @VladMatvienko it always returns 0

Comment: 0 is `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`. This means that the permission was granted.

Comment: @VladMatvienko even if i deny permission it gives me value 0

Comment: Then the subject of your post should have been so.

Comment: `when the user clicks on Deny permission i am not able to open another activity`. So you ment: `when the user clicks on Deny permission i get a PERMISSION_GRANTED`. Please adapt your post.

Comment: @greenapps yess

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting two permissions with:

```
new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}
```

But in `onActivityResult()` you are only looking at `grantResults[0]`.

Those are arrays: `String permissions[], int[] grantResults`.

Inspect them all.

Update:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions().
```

You have that code twice. But the first one you commented. The second one is on the wrong place. Use only the first one.

Comment: even if i request one permission i get same values , my result is always Granted even if its denied

Comment: Go to Android Settings Apps and switch the permission off for your app for a test.

Comment: `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`. You have that code twice. But the first one you commented. The second one is on the wrong place. Use only the first one.